# Como gravar checkbox e Id de produto no MySQL

Tags: php

Estou tentando gravar alguns `checkbox` mais o `ID` do produto em minha base de dados `MySQL` mas não estou conseguindo, o que tenho até o momento é isso:

O formulário:

```
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="cores[]" value="<?php echo $row_RsCores['id_cor_textura']; ?>" />
<input name="IdProduto" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_produto; ?>">
```

O script que deveria realizar a gravação:

```
// RESGATE DAS VARIÁVEIS
$IdProduto = $_POST['IdProduto'];
$itens = $_REQUEST['cores'];

if (!empty($itens)) {                
    $qtd = count($itens);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $qtd; $i++) {
        // echo $itens[$i];//imprime o item corrente

        mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
        $query = "INSERT INTO produto_textura  
            (id_produto,
            id_cor_textura
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ('$IdProduto',
            '$itens[$i]')";
     }

   $queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die( "Erro ao inserir checks no banco de dados.");
}
```

O erro que ocorre é esse:

```
"Erro ao inserir checks no banco de dados."
```

Meu `MySQL` está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ve qual o erro que esta dando? $queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: Olá @MarceloDiniz, simplesmente me apareceu "1" e está sendo enviado para o banco somente o último registro.

Comment: Sempre é o mesmo id de produto(aquele input hidden)? e ` mysql_select_db` deve estar fora do for. Outro teste que pode fazer é imprimir as sqls geradas e executar todas elas no banco de uma vez só.

Comment: Olá $rray, sim o produto será inserido somente uma vez e dei um echo para mostrar a sql gerada e ela só me mostra o último registro de 4 que estou tentando iserir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O último registro é inserido porque o valor de `$query` é reatibuido a cada volta do for, ou seja o `mysql_query()` deve estar dentro do for para inserir N registros.

Olhe o problema:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $qtd; $i++) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO produto_textura  
            (id_produto,
            id_cor_textura
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ('$IdProduto',
            '$itens[$i]')";
} // <--- fim do for

//apenas o último valor dentro de $query será inserido.
$queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die( "Erro ao inserir checks no banco de dados.");
```

É possível fazer algumas simplificações, como montar um template de um insert com N values assim apenas uma consulta é enviada ao banco. Remova o `mysql_select_db()` de dentro do for.

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);

```
$IdProduto = $_POST['IdProduto'];
$itens = $_REQUEST['cores'];

if (!empty($itens)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO produto_textura (id_produto, id_cor_textura) VALUES ";                
    foreach($itens as $item){
        $query .= sprintf("('%s','%s'),", $IdProduto, $item);
    }
    $query = trim(',', $query);
    $queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @rray, tinha certeza de que estava cometendo um erro infantil, mas não conseguiu ver o problema, novamente agradeço.

Comment: @adventistapr, qual é o erro do sql?

Comment: Olá @rray, o erro que estava ocorrendo era esse: "Erro ao inserir checks no banco de dados.", mas o mesmo estava acontecendo porque a lógica inicial estava com uma falha de programação.
Obrigado pelo excelente código completando a sua resposta, excelente.

Answer (score 1):

As colunas `id_produto` e `id_cor_textura` são do tipo int e você está tentando inserir valores do tipo `string`. Além disso, está tentando inserir `"$IdProduto"` ao invés do valor da variável `IdProduto`.

Altere a query para inserir os valores com os tipos corretos e referências corretas:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO produto_textura  
            (id_produto,
            id_cor_textura
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ($IdProduto,
            $itens[$i])";
```

Caso não dê certo, troque o resultado da query para que mostre o erro da execução da query:

```
$queryExec = mysql_query($query, $conexao) or die( "Erro ao inserir registro no  banco de dados: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer: "Além disso, está tentando inserir "$IdProduto" ao invés do valor da variável IdProduto." A variável $IdProduto que está na query está com o valor resgatado do meu IdProduto vindo do meu form.